# which file formats does opc ua server support?

Tags: opc, opc-ua

i want to receive data from an OPC UA Server in my big data environment through nifi, i want to know which file formats does OPC UA Server support to send data?

Answer (score 1):

"**Message Formats**
OPC-UA supports two message formats: UA Binary and XML."

https://readthedocs.web.cern.ch/display/ICKB/OPC-UA+Summary

Comment: Those are the encodings... i want to know about supported file formats like csv, text etc

Comment: @rohit, let's say OPC UA server "supports" png. What that means actually?

Comment: i am a beginner to OPC UA,i just want to know what formats of data can be transferred through OPC UA?

Comment: @rohit, ok, in such case you are looking for "OPC UA Part 03 - Address Space Model 1.03 Specification", chapter 8. There are type listed with appropriate description.